# Show that if $\int_0^1 f(x) v(x) dx = 0$ for every function v for which $\int_0^1 v(x) dx = 0$, then f is constant.

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Show that if $\int_0^1 f(x) v(x) dx = 0$ for every function v for which $\int_0^1 v(x) dx = 0$, then f is constant.
I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Probably need that $f$ is continuous, or the conclusion that $f$ is constant "almost everywhere."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Let $v(x)=f(x)-\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt$.

Comment: can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Then $\int_0^1 v^2(x)dx = \int_0^1 f(x)v(x)dx - \int_0^1 f(x)dx \int_0^1 v(x)dx = 0$.

Comment: thank you. but does that lead to f=c?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, then yes. Otherwise $f$ is a.e. constant.